# Maintain Colorization of output when piping process stdout

Tags: dart

In my command-line application, I call a Powershell script. This script ends up calling other command-line tools, which produce color output. I have the process's stdout piped to stdout, and wait for the process to finish. The issue is that the piped output is no longer colored.

Here's a sample:

```dart
var proc = await Process.start('powershell', ['mvn clean']);
proc.stdout.pipe(stdout);
Future.wait([proc.exitCode]);
```

This is just an example - not my actual code.

`mvn clean` produces color output, but the output I'm seeing is not in color.

How can I make the piping preserve the color?

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with Dart.  Possibly `mvn` detects that it's not writing to a tty and changes its behavior.  Is the output colorized if, say, you run `mvn clean` and redirect its output?